# Browsers remember old .htaccess and don't update

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, xampp

I have recently encountered one of the weirdest bugs I have ever seen. I am using stock instalation of XAMPP server and Netbeans as an IDE.

1. I created .htaccess in the root folder and added a simple rule `RewriteRule x /a` (**rule one**).
2. I tested this rule in Chrome which successfully redirected to `localhost/a`.
3. I changed the code inside the .htaccess to `RewriteRule x /b` (**rule two**).
4. When tested in Chrome, it kept redirecting to `localhost/a` (**rule one**) even after restarting chrome and the server.
5. I tested the **rule two** in Firefox and it successfully redirected to `localhost/b` - **rule two**.
6. I changed the code inside the .htaccess to `RewriteRule x /c` (**rule three**).
7. When tested in Mozilla, it kept redirecting to `localhost/b` (**rule two**).
8. Now I have .htaccess with **rule three**, Chrome using **rule one** and Firefox using 
   **rule two**.

The code previews of the rules are reduced. The whole code looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule x /a [L,R=301]
```

How can I force the server/browser to update it's configuration?

Comment: Have you tried deleting cache from your browser? ctrl+shift+delete

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Comment: That works, thank you. I thought that .htaccess isn't saved in cache because it's a server-side thing.

Comment: You are correct, it's not saved in the cache.  The cache was remembering the original redirection response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser remembers the old .htaccess redirect rules. To update them, you need to delete your cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try Incognito mode or close & reopen your browser.